# Iterating a dataframe with 2 variables for str_replace_all in R/tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a reference table of find/replaces:

```
find | replace
aaa | bbb
ccc | ddd
```

which I have read into a simple findreplace_df dataframe.

And I'm trying to create a function to replace every occurrence of aaa with bbb in long strings within a mutate_all:

```
fix <- function(df){
  df <- df %>%
    mutate_all(list(~ str_replace_all(
      .,
      quotemeta(find),
      quotemeta(replace)
    )))
  return(df)
}
```

I can obviously do:

```
for(find in findreplace_df){
    for(replace in findreplace_df){
          df <- df %>%
    mutate_all(list(~ str_replace_all(
      .,
      quotemeta(find),
      quotemeta(replace)
    )))
    }
}
```

But that seems overly cumbersome. Is there a better way to pass the find and replace variables into a single loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find and replace x1->y1,...,xn->yn can be done without a loop:

```
library(stringi)
strings=c('aaaa','bbbbb','ccccc','ddddd')
patterns=c('aaa','ccc')
replacements=c('bbb','ddd')
stri_replace_all_fixed(strings,patterns,replacements,vectorize_all=F)
[1] "bbba"  "bbbbb" "dddcc" "ddddd"
```

see also `stri_replace_all_regex`

You may also want to do the find and replace for all of the columns in a data.table/data.frame. For this, it is natural to apply or loop over columns, and this is sufficiently fast unless you have a very large number of columns, e.g.,

```
fix = function(df,patterns,replacements){
  string_columns = names(df)[lapply(x,typeof)=='character']
  for(colname in string_columns){
    df[[colname]] = stri_replace_all_fixed(
      df[[colname]],patterns,replacements,vectorize_all=F
    )
  }
}

df = fix(df)
```

Note: this is likely to be faster with data.table:

```
fix = function(DT,patterns,replacements){
  string_columns = names(DT)[lapply(x,typeof)=='character']
  for(colname in string_columns){
    DT[,(colname):=stri_replace_all_fixed(
      get(colname),patterns,replacements,vectorize_all=F
    ]
  }
}

require(data.table)
df = setDT(df)
df = fix(df)
```

Comment: That doesn't error out, but it also doesn't fire the replacements.

Comment: ```
fix <- function(df) {
  df <- df %>%
    mutate_all(list(
      ~ stri_replace_all_fixed(.,
                               patterns,
                               replacements, vectorize_all = F)
    ))
  
  return(df)
}
```

Comment: is the problem that you want to do the find and replace for all columns of df, not just one column?